# Powershell ISE addon working when using GUI menu but not when using its assigned custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: powershell

I still use the ISE on occasion and decided to attempt a custom ISE addon that emulates VS Code's Delete Line `Ctrl+Shift+K` keyboard shortcut.  For the moment, this rough draft doesn't delete multiple lines if selected (that functionality will be added later), only the line the cursor is on:

```
[void]$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Delete Line", {
    $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectCaretLine()
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{DEL}")
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{DEL}")
}, "Ctrl+Shift+K")
```

What I discovered is that this runs as intended when using clicking on the ISE's menu (`Add-ons > Delete Line`) but not when using its assigned keyboard shortcut (`Ctrl+Shift+K`).  Using the keyboard shortcut runs everything I've put in the code block thus far except the SendWait() method(s).
The result when using the keyboard shortcut is what you would expect `$psise.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectCaretLine()` to do - highlight the line that the cursor is currently on - it just doesn't send 'Delete' twice.  The console output is identical when using either method (GUI vs keyboard shortcut).  I've run into some goofy things when using Winforms classes within the ISE, but the difference in behavior between using the ISE Add-ons menu vs keyboard shortcut is new to me.  I've googled for PowerShell ISE SendKeys and ISE SendWait etc and have come up empty.
I'm open to suggestions on a better method (regex, pinvoke/embedded Win32, etc) but am hoping to gain some insight into what's happening under the hood within ISE.
I know, I know - I already use VS Code for a lot and ISE is dying, but this has me curious now and I'd like to know either how to fix this or at least understand why the SendWait method isn't playing well with the ISE.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** removing my previous answer, since you had issues with the approach.***

Refactoring to just this, fully tested/validated for what you say you want. I'd still work to avoid Send-Keys, unless there is no other option.

```
Function Delete-Line
{
    $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectCaretLine()
    # Pause the allow for Send-Keys to work for HotKey use
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{DEL}')
}

$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Delete Current Line", {Delete-Line}, 'Ctrl+Shift+K')
```

You of course can adjust that time to fit your response time. Say, using milliseconds vs seconds. This timing is not absolute with Send-Keys. Each machine you use this on may need a time adjustment. Hence the reason to use another more efficient approach.

Comment: This does not emulate VS Code's 'Delete Line'.  This solution requires that you first have text selected.  VS Code's 'Delete Line' function will delete the actual line(s) regardless if text is selected or not (e.g. when you have cursors on multiple lines and without any selected text) - this solution simply replaces text and doesn't delete the actual line.  If the text is already selected, wouldn't you just press Delete/Backspace since you've already gone to the trouble of using an input device to select the text to begin with?

Comment: That is all your code is doing with that caret selection, but only one line at a time. To get multiple, you need to code for that.

Comment: The question addresses the multiline aspect (it isn't coded yet, and will be coded later). 
 The question is about why the ISE menu executes the custom addon code block correctly but invoking the keyboard shortcut does not.

Comment: Your issue is that Send-Keys is just not reliable. Lots can interfere with it. This is why Start-Sleep is often used with it, because of timing issues regarding it. So, selecting from the menu, give a period between click and the command. HotKey selection does not. See my working update for you. The $psISE does provide a Remove method. See my update for you.